# Center of a simplex given its vertices

Tags: euclidean-geometry, simplex

We have been given $n+1$ points $v_0$,$v_1$,$\dots$,$v_n$ in general position in $n$ dimensions where $n\geq2$

1. what is the formula for the center of the simplex?
2. If say some $k+1$ of the points (where $k$ is in $\{2,2,3,\dots,n\}$) lie on the same $k$-dimensional hyperplane, would the center formula for the lower dimensional simplex be any different?

Comment: When you say center, do you mean center of mass?

Comment: I will be happy with any of the standard definitions! If there are multiple feel free to post all!

Comment: The center of mass is simply the average of the coordinates of the points i.e. $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n v_i$. The formula wouldn't change if the simplex was degenerate, but it probably wouldn't be calculating what you want (or maybe not)? You might want to entirely remove any points that lie in the interior of the k dimensional polyhedron.

Comment: @AlanAbraham Given the averaged center and $n+1$ points $v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n$, is it possible to guess if the simplex was degenerate without doing any determinant computation and only polynomially many operations?

Comment: @AlanAbraham no determinant or Gram schmidt!

Comment: I mean you can just do rref, but that's not any easier complexity wise